# MYSQL delete query mystery

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables; one called `devices` and one called `permanent_users`.

I am trying to delete the devices that were created over 5 minutes ago and the "REALM" (taken from permanent users - inner join) equals "MYREALM".

The below query does not delete anything until there actually is a (at least one) device created over 5 minutes ago belonging to the realm MYREALM... but it deletes ALL records from the devices table!

I have already lost over 6K devices by mistake. Below is my `DELETE` statement -
 what am I doing wrong here?

```
delete devices from devices
inner join (SELECT
  permanent_users.realm,
  devices.name,
  devices.created,
  TimeDiff(Now(), devices.created) AS TimeDifference
FROM
  permanent_users
  INNER JOIN devices ON devices.permanent_user_id = permanent_users.id
WHERE
  (TimeDiff(Now(), devices.created)> '00:05' )AND
  (permanent_users.realm = 'WAVELOC')) myquery;
```

Below is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `permanent_users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `token` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `auth_type` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'sql',
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `last_accept_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_reject_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_accept_nas` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_reject_nas` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_reject_message` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `perc_time_used` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `perc_data_used` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_used` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_cap` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_used` int(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_cap` int(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_cap_type` enum('hard','soft') DEFAULT 'soft',
  `data_cap_type` enum('hard','soft') DEFAULT 'soft',
  `realm` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `realm_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `profile` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `profile_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `from_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `to_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `track_auth` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `track_acct` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `static_ip` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `extra_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `extra_value` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `country_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `language_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7231 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `devices` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `last_accept_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_reject_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_accept_nas` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_reject_nas` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_reject_message` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `permanent_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  `perc_time_used` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `perc_data_used` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_used` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_cap` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_used` int(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_cap` int(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_cap_type` enum('hard','soft') DEFAULT 'soft',
  `data_cap_type` enum('hard','soft') DEFAULT 'soft',
  `realm` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `realm_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `profile` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `profile_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `from_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `to_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `callingstationid` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `acctstarttime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2941 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I am getting all sorts of errors running your suggestions! my sql version is:
root@vmi83670:~# mysql -V
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.53, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3

Sorry for rudamental method, but I dont know how to show myt data in a better way.

[The "permanent_users" table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzcBi.png)

[The "devices" table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTJTe.png)

so... delete devices that are over 5 mins old and are part of the relam "WAVELOC"...

Comment: Can you also post some sample data from both tables? Also, you should **always** try `DELETE` and `UPDATE` queries on a demo db first.

Comment: You can probably remove many of the extra columns from your table definitions paring it down to just those necessary to illustrate your issue, such as just the primary keys, shared foreign key columns, and specific columns of interest like `realm[_id]` and appropriate date columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to:

```
Delete d
  from devices d
  join permanent_users pu
    on pu.id = d.permanent_user_id
   and pu.realm_id = d.realm_id
   and pu.realm = d.realm
   and pu.realm = 'WAVELOC'
 where now() - d.created > 300;
```

Is that correct?

Or is this one correct?

```
Delete d
  from devices d
  join permanent_users pu
    on pu.id = d.permanent_user_id
   and pu.realm = 'WAVELOC'
 where now() - d.created > 300;
```

It's not clear if the `realm` and `realm_id` in `devices` should be correlated with those in `permanent_users` or not.

Date arithmatic in MySQL returns the number of seconds between the two datetime columns.  300 seconds is equivalent to 5 minutes.

Comment: Hi Thank you! but I get the following error in TOAD: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'd
 where datediff(Now(), d.created) > '00:05')
   AND exists (select 1 from pe' at line 1

Comment: @XeWonder Sorry about that.  I failed to test before posting.  Fixed syntax to work with MySQL's flavor of DELETE.

Comment: Second one works a treat!! Thank you VERY much!!! not sure how to accept as answer!

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `WHERE` clause for your `DELETE` statement. If you tell the DBMS to delete records in a table, but dont specify which ones, it is going to delete all of them.

> **Note**: Be careful when deleting records in a table! Notice the WHERE
>   clause in the DELETE statement. The WHERE clause specifies which
>   record(s) that should be deleted. If you omit the WHERE clause, all
>   records in the table will be deleted!

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp

As a side note, if youre the DBA, you should make a copy of your database to use a development enviornment so you can test your code out and not have to worry about destroying your production data.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if you don't display the table definition, and I suppose there are some glitches or syntax errors there, but I'd rather structure the query as this:

delete from devices d where d.id in ( make here the inner join that returns only the id of the devices you want ).

Also, in the inner join, you should only get the field you want to match between the tables, and let the rest of the params for the where section.

It should be something like this:

```
delete from devices d where d.id in (

SELECT q.permanent_user_id

FROM
  permanent_users p
  INNER JOIN devices q ON q.permanent_user_id = p.id
WHERE
  (TimeDiff(Now(), q.created)> '00:05' )AND
  (p.realm = 'WAVELOC')
)
);
```

Try the inner select before to execute the delete, that should be your normal operation, to avoid losing data in the case of a malformed query.

Comment: Hi, inner select works great... but when selection all the code i get error on TOAD:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'd where d.id in (

SELECT q.permanent_user_id

FROM
  permanent_users p
  ' at line 1

Comment: I'm not so sure this will work, since `d.id` from the delete portion is not the same ID as `q.permantent_user_id`

Comment: @Sentinel, that's true, I was trying to figure out the table structure, as it wasn't present the first time the OP was asking, but it's true I'm pairing both main id's instead of the fk. Good point.